# Name for server-side served HTML

Tags: html, naming-conventions

I am looking for a one-word or standard term for RESTful HTML rendered server side and sent to the client. Don't know if there is a specialized or preferred word for this.

I Can't find anything. Is there one?

Comment: RESTful, preferrably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages that are generated rather than stored as static files, are called **dynamic web pages**. If they are created on the server, generally **server-side scripting** is used to generate them.

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page